# C# XNA 4.0 frame rate problems, possible .SetData missuse

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, xna-4.0, terrain

I have a problem regarding frame rate drop while trying to make real time 3D terrain changes. I use C#, XNA 4.0 and VS 2010. This is my old school project and time has come to finish it.

I already did terrain generation from image file, with all effects and stuff and it is running smoothly no matter what resolution image file is. Problem is with my terrain editor. I want it to be able to manually alter the terrain. I did that part too, but it works only if terrain size is equal or less than 128x128 pixels. If the terrain size is greater I start to get frame rate drops around 150x150 pixels, and it is completely unmanageable if terrain size is greater than 512x512 pixels.

I already tried several approaches:

- tried to use threads, but then I get weird error saying something like "Draw method can be called in one thread at a time" or something similar, and that I can't resolve.
- next I tried to use DynamicVertexBuffer and DynamicIndexBuffer. That helped a lot and now my code is working with acceptable frame rate for terrain size of up to 256x256 pixels.

Have a look at my code:

```
    public void ChangeTerrain(float[,] heightData)
    {
        int x, y;
        int v = 1;
        if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && currentMouseState.X < 512)
        {
            x = (int)currentMouseState.X / 2;
            y = (int)currentMouseState.Y / 2;
            if (x < 5)
                x = 5;
            if (x >= 251)
                x = 251;
            if (y < 5)
                y = 5;
            if (y >= 251)
                y = 251;

            for (int i = x - 4; i < x + 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = y - 4; j < y + 4; j++)
                {
                    if (i == x - 4 || i == x + 3 || j == y - 4 || j == y + 3)
                        v = 3;
                    else
                        v = 5;
                    if (heightData[i, j] < 210)
                    {
                        heightData[i, j] += v;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentMouseState.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && currentMouseState.X < 512)
        {
            x = (int)currentMouseState.X / 2;
            y = (int)currentMouseState.Y / 2;
            if (x < 5)
                x = 5;
            if (x >= 251)
                x = 251;
            if (y < 5)
                y = 5;
            if (y >= 251)
                y = 251;

            for (int i = x - 4; i < x + 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = y - 4; j < y + 4; j++)
                {
                    if (heightData[i, j] > 0)
                    {
                        heightData[i, j] -= 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.R))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                    heightData[i, j] = 0f;
        }
        SetUpTerrainVertices();
        CalculateNormals();
        terrainVertexBuffer.SetData(vertices, 0, vertices.Length);
    }
```

I work with resolution of 1024x512 pixels, so I scale mouse position by 1/2 to get terrain position. I use left and right mouse button to alter terrain, i.e. to alter heightData from which 3D terrain is generated. 
Last 3 lines create Vertices from new heightData, calculate Normals so shades could be applied and last line is just throwing Vertices data to Vertex Buffer.

Prior to that, I set up dynamic Vertex and Index buffer in LoadContent method and call initial Vertices and Indices setup. This method (ChangeTerrain) is called from Update method.

I did some debugging and found out that maximum size of vertices in most extreme case would be around 260000 +- few thousands. Is it possible that .SetData is so much time consuming it is causing frame rate drops? Or is it something else? How can I fix that and make my editor functioning normally for any terrain size?

Also, i red that I need to use this code with DynamicVertexBuffer, but I can't make it work in XNA 4.0.

```
terrainVertexBuffer.ContentLost += new EventHandler(TerrainVertexBufferContentLost);

public void TerrainVertexBufferContentLost()
{
terrainVertexBuffer(vertices, 0, vertices.Length, SetDataOptions.NoOverwrite);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

This is my SetUpTerrainVertices code:

```
private void SetUpTerrainVertices()
        {
            vertices = new VertexPositionNormalColored[terrainWidth * terrainLength];

            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength; y++)
                {
                    vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, heightData[x, y], -y);
vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Color =  Color.Gray;

                }
            }
        }
```

And my CalculateNormals

```
private void CalculateNormals()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
                vertices[i].Normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length / 3; i++)
            {
                int index1 = indices[i * 3];
                int index2 = indices[i * 3 + 1];
                int index3 = indices[i * 3 + 2];

                Vector3 side1 = vertices[index1].Position - vertices[index3].Position;
                Vector3 side2 = vertices[index1].Position - vertices[index2].Position;
                Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);

                vertices[index1].Normal += normal;
                vertices[index2].Normal += normal;
                vertices[index3].Normal += normal;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
                vertices[i].Normal.Normalize();
        }
```

I set up vertex and index buffers in XNA LoadContent Method using lines:

```
terrainVertexBuffer = new DynamicVertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionNormalColored.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length,
                BufferUsage.None);

terrainIndexBuffer = new DynamicIndexBuffer(device, typeof(int), indices.Length, BufferUsage.None);
```

I call ChangeTerrain method from Update and this is how i Draw:

```
private void DrawTerrain(Matrix currentViewMatrix)
        {
            device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
            device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);
            effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Colored"];
            Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
            effect.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(worldMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(currentViewMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xEnableLighting"].SetValue(true);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                device.Indices = terrainIndexBuffer;
                device.SetVertexBuffer(terrainVertexBuffer);

                device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, vertices.Length, 0, indices.Length / 3);

            }
        }
```

EDIT2:

Ok, I decided to go for your second suggestion and got into some problems. I modified my methods like this:

```
public void ChangeTerrain(Texture2D heightmap)
        {
            Color[] mapColors = new Color[256 * 256];
            Color[] originalColors = new Color[256 * 256];
            for (int i = 0; i < 256 * 256; i++)
                originalColors[i] = new Color(0, 0, 0);

            heightMap2.GetData(mapColors);
            device.Textures[0] = null;
            device.Textures[1] = null;
            int x, y;
            int v = 1;
            if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && currentMouseState.X < 512)
            {
                x = (int)currentMouseState.X / 2;
                y = (int)currentMouseState.Y / 2;
                if (x < 4)
                    x = 4;
                if (x >= 251)
                    x = 251;
                if (y < 4)
                    y = 4;
                if (y >= 251)
                    y = 251;                

                for (int i = x-4; i < x+4; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = y-4; j < y+4; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == x - 4 || i == x + 3 || j == y - 4 || j == y + 3)
                            v = 3;
                        else
                            v = 5;
                        if (mapColors[i + j * 256].R < 210)
                        {
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].R += (byte)(v);
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].G += (byte)(v);
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].B += (byte)(v);
                        }
                        heightMap2.SetData(mapColors);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentMouseState.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && currentMouseState.X < 512)
            {
                x = (int)currentMouseState.X / 2;
                y = (int)currentMouseState.Y / 2;
                if (x < 4)
                    x = 4;
                if (x >= 251)
                    x = 251;
                if (y < 4)
                    y = 4;
                if (y >= 251)
                    y = 251; 

                for (int i = x - 4; i < x + 4; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = y - 4; j < y + 4; j++)
                    {
                        if (mapColors[i + j * 256].R > 0)
                        {
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].R -= 1;
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].G -= 1;
                            mapColors[i + j * 256].B -= 1;
                        }
                        heightMap2.SetData(mapColors);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.R))
                heightMap2.SetData(originalColors);
        }
```

Generating flat surface - only once in `LoadContent()` method:
`vertices` are assigned only once

```
private void SetUpTerrainVertices()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < terrainLength; y++)
                {
                    vertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, 0, -y);
                    vertices[x + y * terrainLength].Color = Color.Gray;
                }
            }
        }
```

`Draw` method is same as previous, but with one extra line:

`effect.Parameters["xTexture0"].SetValue(heightMap2);`

also, I made new technique called `Editor` and it looks like this:

```
//------- Technique: Editor --------
struct EditorVertexToPixel
{
    float4 Position       : POSITION;    
    float4 Color        : COLOR0;
    float LightingFactor: TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TextureColor : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct EditorPixelToFrame
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

EditorVertexToPixel EditorVS( float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor: COLOR, float3 inNormal: NORMAL, float2 inTextureColor: TEXCOORD1)
{    
    EditorVertexToPixel Output = (EditorVertexToPixel)0;
    float4x4 preViewProjection = mul (xView, xProjection);
    float4x4 preWorldViewProjection = mul (xWorld, preViewProjection);

    float4 Height;
    float4 position2 = inPos;
    position2.y += Height;

    Output.Color = inColor;
    Output.Position = mul(position2, preWorldViewProjection);
    Output.TextureColor = inTextureColor;

    float3 Normal = normalize(mul(normalize(inNormal), xWorld));    
    Output.LightingFactor = 1;
    if (xEnableLighting)
        Output.LightingFactor = saturate(dot(Normal, -xLightDirection));

    return Output;    
}

EditorPixelToFrame EditorPS(EditorVertexToPixel PSIn)
{
    EditorPixelToFrame Output = (EditorPixelToFrame)0;   

    //float4 height2 = tex2D(HeightSAmpler, PSIn.TextureColor); 
    float4 colorNEW = float4(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.6f, 1);
    Output.Color = PSIn.Color * colorNEW;
    Output.Color.rgb *= saturate(PSIn.LightingFactor) + xAmbient;    

    return Output;
}

technique Editor
{
    pass Pass0
    {  
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 EditorVS();
        PixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 EditorPS();
    }
}
```

this code doesn't work because `float4 Height` is not set. What I wanted to do is to sample texture colors into `float4 Height` (using `Sample`), but I can not use sampler in `VertexShader`. I get error message "X4532 cannot map expression to vertex shader instruction set".

Then, I red that you can use `SampleLevel` in `VertexShader` to sample color data and thought I found solution, but I get strange error that is only documented in one Russian blog, but I can't speak or read Russian. Error is: "X4814 unexpected Alias on texture declaration"

Is there a way to sample colors in `PixelShader` and then pass them to `VertexShader`?

This could work cos I managed to set `float4 Height` to various values and it altered vertices height. Problem is, I don't know how to read texture color in `VertexShader`, or how to pass red texture color data from `PixelShader` to `VertexShader`.

EDIT3:
I think I found solution. Was searching the net and found out about `tex2Dlod` function to use as `VertexShader` texture sampler. But there are different syntax displayed and I can't make them work.

Can anyone point out on good HLSL literature to learn a bit about HLSL coding. This task seems pretty easy, but somehow, I can't make it to work.

Comment: That last bit of code seems to be missing "`.SetData`", but the general idea is right (if the device is lost, the GPU-data needs to be refreshed). You need to provide more useful code. The code you have posted (for modifying `heightData`) seems pretty reasonable. Can you show us `SetUpTerrainVertices` and `CalculateNormals`. It's probably also worth showing us how you create and draw your `terrainVertexBuffer`.

Comment: Maybe I have a solution. I red that I need to divide my map into tiles and then alter one tile at the time while displaying just a portion of my map. I will try that tomorrow, but it is kind of stupid, or to say it better, unpractical to alter 16 128x128 resolution images to get one 512x512 map.

Comment: Also, somewhere, I red that you can draw only vertices facing camera. Could that help in my project? Could that make frame rate drops manageable at least for 512x512 resolution?

Comment: The GPU will automatically cull back-facing polygons faster than you can (use `RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise`).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I can't offer "real" performance advice - because I haven't measured your code. And measuring is probably the most important part of performance optimisation - you need to be able to answer the questions: "am I slower than my performance target?" and "why am I slower than my target?"

That being said - here are the things that stand out to me as a seasoned developer:

---

> This method (ChangeTerrain) is called from Update method

You should probably consider splitting that method up so that, rather than recreating your data every frame, it only does work when the terrain is actually changed.

---

```
vertices = new VertexPositionNormalColored[terrainWidth * terrainLength];
```

Allocating a new `vertices` buffer each frame is *huge* memory allocation (**6MB** at 512x512). This is going to put a big strain on the garbage collector - and **I suspect this is the primary cause of your performance issues.**

Given that you're about to set all the data in that array anyway, simply delete that line and the old data in the array will be overwritten.

---

Better yet, you could leave the data that doesn't change as-is, and only modify the vertices that are actually changed. In much the same way you are doing for `heightData`.

As part of this, it would be a very good idea to modify `CalculateNormals` so that, rather than having to rely on the index buffer and going through every triangle, it could calculate the indices of surrounding vertices (that form triangles) for any specific vertex - something you can do because `vertices` is ordered. Again, kind of like what you're doing for `heightData`.

---

```
terrainVertexBuffer.SetData(vertices, 0, vertices.Length);
```

This is sending the full 6MB buffer to the GPU. There are versions of `SetData` that only send a subset of the full buffer to the GPU. You should probably try and use these.

Just remember that each `SetData` call comes with some overhead, so don't get too granular. It's probably best to have just one call per vertex buffer, even if that means some unmodified parts of the buffer must be sent.

This is probably the only place where "chunking" your terrain would have an significant impact, as it would allow you to specify a tighter region for each `SetData` call - allowing you to send less unmodified data. (I'll leave figuring out why this is the case as an exercise.)

(You're already using `DynamicVertexBuffer`, which is good, because this means the GPU will automatically handle the pipeline issues of having its buffer changed on-the-fly.)

---

Finally, if performance is still an issue, you could consider a different approach entirely.

One example might be to offload the calculation of the geometry to the GPU. You'd convert your `heightData` to a texture, and use a vertex shader (with a flat grid of vertices as input) to sample that texture and output the appropriate positions and normals.

One big advantage of this approach is that `heightData` can be a *lot* smaller (0.25MB at 512x512) than your vertex buffer - that's much less data that the CPU needs to process and send to the GPU.

Comment: Now that you said it, I realize I made really inefficient code. For changing 1% of `heightData` field, program calculates for 100%. That is a lot of redundant information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just a question...How am I supposed to read texture colors in vertex shader in order to alter my flat surface? I decided for your second suggestion, it seems like a lot elegant way to create editor.

Comment: That's probably a big enough question to put into a new one, either here or on the [GDSE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site. But the basic answer is that it's the same as in a pixel shader - pass a sampler and a texture coordinate to [`tex2d`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509677(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the colour value and convert that to a height.